# Large amount of screen tearing/flicker when using bitmaps with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm getting a rather insane amount of flicker in my app. As you can see below, if I resize the main window, or one of the sub `SplitterWindow` sashes, the whole program tears apart.

[image: Resize tearing 001]
[image: Resize tearing 002]
[image]

I suspect this is due, mostly, to the background images I'm using. I'm using the code found [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/), which I'll also paste below. I imagine that this is a buffering issue? But I read through the buffering section and left puzzled. Not to mention, I don't understand what exactly the code to draw the background is doing in the first place, so it's tough to pin down what's causing the issue.

```
def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    """
    Add a picture to the background
    """
    # yanked from ColourDB.py
    dc = evt.GetDC()

    if not dc:
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
        dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.Clear()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap("butterfly.jpg")
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Does anyone know how to reduce the rate of flickering in a wxpython application?

Comment: look into double buffering maybe?

Comment: If you want to minimize flickering, never allow the background to erase because you might see the partially erased or partially painted window. You need to paint the whole thing over the top of the previous contents. That's why double buffering is helpful - you erase the buffer, not the window, and you never see the intermediate state.